# understanding the impact of "More than 1 Couchbase Environments found"

Tags: java, couchbase, spring-data-couchbase, couchbase-java-api

I'm trying to understand the true impact of using multiple couchbase environments and the following warning:

> More than 1 Couchbase Environments found (2), this can have severe impact on performance and stability. Reuse environments!

I've done some googling and found an example where having too many cluster instances results in an [out of memory error](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/getting-out-of-memory-exception-while-creating-multiple-couchbase-environments/3585). I've also seen [this post](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/more-than-1-couchbase-environments-found/2434) where it is recommended to use one DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment, but it doesn't go too much into the actual impact of using multiple environments. In the documentation, [this section](https://docs.couchbase.com/java-sdk/2.7/managing-connections.html#concurrency) mentions that "the resources in the environment (thread pools for I/O and computation) are reused" across clusters in a given environment. Can anyone else provide more detail on what happens when multiple couchbase environments are used?